# Invalid JSON when parsing objects containing html as a string property

Tags: c#, javascript, json, parsing, invalid-characters

I've got a controller action that just displays a JSON result: http://pkssblog-stage.azurewebsites.net/BlogPosts/GetAll. The object has a property called Content which is basically the HTML content of a post.

The problem is I always get invalid JSON exceptions when parsing it using the JsonObject.Parse in WinRT, the JSON.parse within a browser console or even JSON validators online.

The weird thing is that I don't get issues when I turn it into a javascript object via the console through `var x = jsonstringarray;`

I get in trouble with this specific property (as noted by the online validators):

```
"Content":"\u003cbr\u003eMicrosoft Azure Storage provides many services...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What *exact* error message do you get?

Comment: It passed through JSONLint. What is the exact error. Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Please check the entire json string here: http://pkssblog-stage.azurewebsites.net/BlogPosts/GetAll